# ¿Porque me sale undefined en un array?

Tags: javascript

Cuando quiero mostrar las dos plantas que he creado en el piso me sale lo siguiente:

> Estamos en la planta: `undefined` puerta `undefined` y el propietario es `undefined`

Aquí tengo mi código:

```js
plantas = Array();
function edificio(calle, numero, cp)
{
  // Propiedades
  this.calle = calle;
  this.numero = numero;
  this.cp = cp;

  // Metodos
  this.modificarNumero = modificarNumero;
  this.modificarCalle = modificarCalle;
  this.modificarCodigoPostal = modificarCodigoPostal;
  this.imprimeCalle = imprimeCalle;
  this.imprimeNumero = imprimeNumero;
  this.imprimeCodigoPostal = imprimeCodigoPostal;
  this.agregarPropietario = agregarPropietario;
  this.imprimePlantas = imprimePlantas;
}

this.agregarPlantasYPuerta = function (plantas, puertas)
{

}

this.modificarNumero = function (numero)
{
  this.numero = numero;
}

this.modificarCalle = function (calle)
{
  this.calle = calle;
}

this.modificarCodigoPostal = function (cp)
{
  this.cp = cp;
}

this.imprimeCalle  = function ()
{
  document.write("<br>Este edificio esta en la calle " + this.calle);
}

this.imprimeNumero  = function ()
{
  document.write("<br>Este edificio es el nº " + this.numero);
}

this.imprimeCodigoPostal  = function ()
{
  document.write("<br>Este edificio esta dentro del codigo postal: " + this.cp);
}

this.agregarPropietario = function (planta, puerta, propietario)
{
  plantas.push(
    [
      {"planta":planta,"puerta":puerta,"propietario":propietario}
    ])
}

this.imprimePlantas  = function ()
{
  for(var i=0; i<plantas.length; i++)
  {
    document.write("<br>Estamos en la planta: " + plantas[i].planta + " puerta " +plantas[i].puerta + " y el propietario es " + plantas[i].propietario);
  }
}


var CasaJavi = new edificio("Calle navarra",29,50650);
var CasaAna = new edificio("Calle aaaaaa",2329,'5065dds0');

document.write("Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);
CasaJavi.modificarNumero('50');
document.write("<br>Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);
CasaJavi.modificarCalle('Falsa');
document.write("<br>Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);
CasaJavi.modificarCodigoPostal('50730');
document.write("<br>Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);

CasaAna.imprimeCalle();
CasaAna.imprimeNumero();
CasaAna.imprimeCodigoPostal();
CasaJavi.agregarPropietario(1,2,"Javier Izquierdo");
CasaJavi.agregarPropietario(1,1,"Juan Rodriguez");
CasaJavi.imprimePlantas();
```

¿Alguien sabe porque me esta fallando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique esta parte

```
plantas.push(
    [
      {"planta":planta,"puerta":puerta,"propietario":propietario}
    ])
```

para solucionar seria:

```
plantas.push(

      {"planta":planta,"puerta":puerta,"propietario":propietario}
    )
```

```js
plantas = [];
function edificio(calle,numero,cp)
{
  //Propiedades
  this.calle = calle;
  this.numero = numero;
  this.cp = cp;

  //Metodos
  this.modificarNumero = modificarNumero;
  this.modificarCalle = modificarCalle;
  this.modificarCodigoPostal = modificarCodigoPostal;
  this.imprimeCalle = imprimeCalle;
  this.imprimeNumero = imprimeNumero;
  this.imprimeCodigoPostal = imprimeCodigoPostal;
  this.agregarPropietario = agregarPropietario;
  this.imprimePlantas = imprimePlantas;
}

this.agregarPlantasYPuerta = function (plantas,puertas)
{

}

this.modificarNumero = function (numero)
{
  this.numero = numero;
}

this.modificarCalle = function (calle)
{
  this.calle = calle;
}

this.modificarCodigoPostal = function (cp)
{
  this.cp = cp;
}

this.imprimeCalle  = function ()
{
  document.write("<br>Este edificio esta en la calle " + this.calle);
}

this.imprimeNumero  = function ()
{
  document.write("<br>Este edificio es el nº " + this.numero);
}

this.imprimeCodigoPostal  = function ()
{
  document.write("<br>Este edificio esta dentro del codigo postal: " + this.cp);
}

this.agregarPropietario = function (planta,puerta,propietario)
{
  plantas.push(
    
      {"planta":planta,"puerta":puerta,"propietario":propietario}
    )
}

this.imprimePlantas  = function ()
{
  for(var i=0; i<plantas.length; i++)
  {
    document.write("<br>Estamos en la planta: " + plantas[i].planta + " puerta " +plantas[i].puerta + " y el propietario es " + plantas[i].propietario);
  }
}


var CasaJavi = new edificio("Calle navarra",29,50650);
var CasaAna = new edificio("Calle aaaaaa",2329,'5065dds0');
document.write("Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);
CasaJavi.modificarNumero('50');
document.write("<br>Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);
CasaJavi.modificarCalle('Falsa');
document.write("<br>Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);
CasaJavi.modificarCodigoPostal('50730');
document.write("<br>Vivo en la " + CasaJavi.calle + " nº " + CasaJavi.numero + " y el codigo postal es " + CasaJavi.cp);
CasaAna.imprimeCalle();
CasaAna.imprimeNumero();
CasaAna.imprimeCodigoPostal();
CasaJavi.agregarPropietario(1,2,"Javier Izquierdo");
CasaJavi.agregarPropietario(1,1,"Juan Rodriguez");
CasaJavi.imprimePlantas();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me ha funcionado correctamente.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Alguien sabe porque me esta fallando?

En la función `agregarPropietario`, estas agregando al arreglo `plantas`, un `array` (`[]`) con 1 `object` (`{}`), es decir, que para poder acceder a las propiedades del objeto, aún te falta llegar al primer valor del `array`.

Ejemplo: `plantas[i][0].planta`

Soluciones:

- Modificar que se agrega al arreglo `plantas` en el método `agregarPropietario`:

  ```
  plantas.push({"planta":planta,"puerta":puerta,"propietario":propietario});
  ```
- Modificar como se lee el arreglo `plantas` en el método `imprimePlantas`:

  ```
  var planta = plantas[i][0];
  document.write("<br>Estamos en la planta: " + planta.planta + " puerta " +planta.puerta + " y el propietario es " + planta.propietario);
  ```

**PD**: Tu código tiene grandes "incoherencias" te recomiendo que leas este articulo: [Introducción a JavaScript orientado a objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introducci%C3%B3n_a_JavaScript_orientado_a_objetos)